# Memory leak in Webcore

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having a fairly weird problem. When I run my app in iOS 5.0 there is no leak but the total Allocation keeps on increasing at about 10KB/Second without me doing anything. I am using a UIWebview within the app.

I ran instruments allocation tool to get the data and found that the following code is causing the leak, but can't understand why this code which seems to be a different thread would cause it. It  does not have any application code. This does not seem to happen on iOS 4.3 at all. Any help will be appreciated:

0 CoreFoundation __CFAllocatorSystemAllocate

1 CoreFoundation CFAllocatorAllocate

2 CoreFoundation __CFBasicHashRehash

3 CoreFoundation __CFBasicHashAddValue

4 CoreFoundation CFBasicHashAddValue

5 CoreFoundation CFSetAddValue

6 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopAddTimer

7 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopAddItemToCommonModes

8 CoreFoundation __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke_0

9 CoreFoundation CFBasicHashApply

10 CoreFoundation CFSetApplyFunction

11 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopAddTimer

12 WebCore WebCore::setSharedTimerFireTime(double)

13 WebCore WebCore::MainThreadSharedTimer::setFireTime(double)

14 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal()

15 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFired()

16 WebCore WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*)

17 CoreFoundation **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**

18 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoTimer

19 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun

20 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific

21 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode

22 WebCore RunWebThread(void*)

23 libSystem.B.dylib _pthread_start

24 libSystem.B.dylib thread_start